# How to delete an App Version from Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I am newbie and I was playing around couple of months back with Google Cloud and by mistake I somehow have added a Version/hello world project that looks like below and it is doing some logging which is taking 100 GB of space and Google  is charging me for that space. I just want to get rid of it but I am not able to do so. Please help me.

Screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Issue: Why am I not able to completely delete it. I am beginner so please guide me how to get rid of it? I am getting charged every month. Where can I click and delete it.

P.S: I know I have not asked this question properly but I don't have the proper terminology knowledge to ask my query properly.

Answer (score 3):

Just click on the square in the left side of the version row in the table pictured in your 1st screenshot to select it and the Delete button *should* activate.

Update:

Hm, ok. Looks like the only remaining version can't be deleted. You could also:

- disable your app if this is the only service in it from the `Settings` Menu.
- delete the app if you no longer need that app ID (you won't be able to re-use that ID for a new app)
- deploy a new version which doesn't do anything, switch traffic to it and delete the old version. I'd make the new version a standard environment one, which has a free quota, instead of a flexible environment one, eventually with just a static dir handler pointing to an empty dir.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this with your CI/CD script. This works with Linux.

```
gcloud app versions delete `gcloud app versions list | sed 's/  */:/g' | cut -f 2 -d : | tail -n +2 | head -n -1` --quiet
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gcloud app versions delete [NAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

For quick and nice way of deleting App Version through CLI :

`gcloud app services delete {services list} --version=XXXX`

Example: `gcloud app services delete night-worker default day-worker --version=version2019`

That way you will save yourself time for deleting App Engine versions.